# Xpath first text before needed tag

Tags: html, xpath

I have some HTML code:

```
<dl>
    <div>
       <div>foo</div>
    <div>
    "I need getting only this text"
    <dd>
       <div>foo</div>
       <div>foo</div>
    </dd>
    <div>
        <div>foo</div>
    <div>
    "I need getting only this text"
    <dd>
        <div>foo</div>
        <div>foo</div>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

So I need getting **only first text before** a required tag(not "foo").
I tried syntax like

> //text()[(preceding::dd)][some integer]

or

> //text()[(preceding::dd)][last()]

but it's all now working for me, because count of **div** with **"foo"** - undefined.
I need some xpath, like //dl/text() but returns direct ancestor of 'dl', no some level deeper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I need getting only first text before a required tag

How about this:

```
//dd/preceding-sibling::text()[1]
```

i.e. find the `dd` tags and then for each of those take the nearest preceding sibling text node.  Given your example this would return a set of two text nodes, each of which contains the text

```
'
    "I need getting only this text"
    '
```

(without the single quotes, i.e. newline, four spaces, double quote, I need getting only this text, double quote, newline, four spaces).